# How to change name and description website?

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script that creates a page based on a template.

```
New-SPWeb -url http://site/project/project01 -template OFFILE#1 -name "01"
Import-SPWeb http://site/project/project01 -Path C:\Backup\tamp.bak
```

Is there a possibility to change the name and description website usign powershell?

The reason I use the exported packages due to the fact that I want to have a library of set right.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to the following should do the trick.

```
$spAssigment = Start-SPAssignment
$web = Get-SPWeb -site http://sitename/sites/site1 -Identity http://site/project/project01 
   -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
$web.Title = "..........."
$web.Update()
Stop-SPAssignment $spAssignment
```

notice: Start-SPAssignment and Stop-SPAssignment are only an alternative way of disposing the SPWeb istance.

---

**EDIT**

I forgot to change the description of the web in the above sample.
Anyway, you could just use Set-SPWeb.

```
Get-SPWeb -Identity http://site/project/project01 | Set-SPWeb 
    -Title "My new title" -Description "My new description"
```

See the sample [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ff607732.aspx)

Comment: Change the description works well. But as I want to change the parameter title, gets an error.

`code` Get-SPWeb http://site/project/project01 | Set-SPWeb -Title "01" `

` Set-SPWeb : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Title'.
At line:1 char:65
+ Get-SPWeb http://site/project/project01 | Set-SPWeb -Title <<<<  "01"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-SPWeb], ParameterBindi
   ngException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint.Powe
   rShell.SPCmdletSetWeb `

Answer (score 0):

This will update the title after the web has been restored:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YOURSiteCollection.test.de
$web.Title="NEW"
$web.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in web sites with non-English Culture Settings.
The solution is:

```
$web = get-spweb("http://pizza.test.it");
$web.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture($web.UICulture, "Margherita");
$web.update()
```